# JS How to convert a normal object to a js model class

Tags: javascript, model

So I am getting a response from my api with an User in it. And I am trying to put it in a user model. This is how I do it at the moment:

```
export default class DefaultUserModel  {
    constructor(data = {}) {
        this.id = data.id ? this.id: null
        this.firstname = data.firstname ? this.firstname: null
        this.lastname = data.lastname ? this.lastname: null
        this.email = data.email ? this.email: null
    }
}

export default class User extends DefaultUserModel{
    constructor(data = {}) {
        super();
        this.hasCoach = data.hasCoach ? this.hasCoach: null
        this.created_at = data.created_at ? this.created_at: null
        this.updated_at = data.updated_at ? this.updated_at: null
    }
}
```

This is how I fill the model:

```
 const newCustomer = new User()
 newCustomer.id = customer.customer.id
 newCustomer.firstname = customer.customer.firstname
 newCustomer.lastname = customer.customer.lastname
 newCustomer.email = customer.customer.email
 newCustomer.hasCoach = customer.customer.hasCoach
 newCustomer.created_at = customer.customer.created_at
 newCustomer.updated_at = customer.customer.updated_at
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: const newCustomer = new User(response.user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nullish coalescing operator `??`:

```
export default class User extends DefaultUserModel {
  constructor(data = {}) {
    super(data);
    this.hasCoach = data.hasCoach ?? null;
    this.created_at = data.created_at ?? null;
    this.updated_at = data.updated_at ?? null;
  }
}
```

Then using following line:
You would fill the `User` object with corresponding data from the incoming array

```
const newCustomer = new User(customer.customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Object destructuring and the spread operator to avoid repetition.
Modify your classes as below

```
export default class DefaultUserModel {
  constructor({ id = null, firstname = null, lastname = null, email = null } = {}) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
  }
}

export default class User extends DefaultUserModel {
  constructor({ hasCoach = null, created_at = null, updated_at = null, ...userData } = {}) {
    super(userData);
    this.hasCoach = hasCoach;
    this.created_at = created_at;
    this.updated_at = updated_at;
  }
}
```

and when you do get your `CustomerData` you can create an object as follows:

```js
const customerData = customer.customer;
const newCustomer = new User({ ...customerData });
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure the props you want, and assign them to `this` inside the `constructor`.

```js
const now = () => new Date().toLocaleDateString('fr-CA');

class DefaultUserModel  {
  constructor(config) {
    const { id = null, firstname = null, lastname = null, email = null } = config;
    Object.assign(this, { id, firstname, lastname, email });
  }
};

class User extends DefaultUserModel {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config);
    const { hasCoach = false, created_at = null, updated_at = null } = config;
    Object.assign(this, { hasCoach, created_at, updated_at });
  }
};

const myUser = new User({
  id: 1,
  firstname: 'Billy',
  lastname: 'Bob',
  email: 'bb@site.net',
  created_at: now()
});

console.log(myUser);
```